# System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda throwing System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

Trying to use ParseLmabda method available in System.Linq.Dynamic.Core library. When I execute the following simple example.

```
using (var context = new EntityContext())
{
    Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> e1 = System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicExpressionParser
        .ParseLambda<Customer, bool>(null, true, "City = @0", "London");

    var customers = context.Customers.Where("@0(it)", e1).ToList();

}
```

it throws the following exception.

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.'
```

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you even need the `el` variable? What about using `Where("City == @0", "London")`?

Comment: exploring the library power of expression which I will be using in my project.

Comment: Well, you're simply using it in a non-valid way. If you've got a specific use-case where you can't use the simple syntax in my previous comment, go ahead and ask about *that* one and I'll try to help.

Comment: Actually I am trying the different overloads of ParseLambda method,  so in this example, I am using overload mentioned here https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions#dynamic-lambda-invocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this code:

```cs
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> e1 = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda<Customer, bool>(null, true, "City = @0", "London");

var customers = Customers.Where(e1).ToList();
```

[image]

## Update (2020-06-01)

Actually, code below should just work fine.

```cs
var e1 = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda<Customer, bool>(new ParsingConfig(), true, "City = @0", "London");
var e2 = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda<Customer, bool>(new ParsingConfig(), true, "c => c.CompanyName != \"test\"");

var customers = context.Customers.ToList().AsQueryable().Where("@0(it) and @1(it)", e1, e2);
```

See example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PF9Htk

Comment: yes it's working, so what is the issue with 
var customers = context.Customers.Where("@0(it)", e1).ToList();
So how can we use multiple expression in Where method?